# Android - setOnClickListener crashing in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imagebutton

I am working on an activity which uses two fragments, one for displaying images on a canvas and the second which features buttons to affect elements on the canvas. I have just set up onClickListeners for the two buttons, and now the program is crashing where it didn't crash before. This happens immediately when it runs, so I don't know what exactly is the problem except that logcat says it's entirely an issue with this fragment. I can only assume that I'm implementing setOnClickListener incorrectly. Could anyone help me to see what I am doing incorrectly?

ToolbarFragment

```
package com.example.chris.drawingtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.example.chris.drawingtest.R;

/**
 * Created by Chris on 11/28/2014.
 */
public class ToolbarFragment extends Fragment {

    ToolSelectionListener mCallback;

    ImageButton pencilButton, eraserButton;

    public interface ToolSelectionListener {
        public void sendNewValue(int newValue);
    }

    public void clicked(ImageButton imageButton) {
        Log.d("we're listening...", "to the buttons!");
        if (imageButton.getId() == eraserButton.getId())
            mCallback.sendNewValue(1);
        else
            mCallback.sendNewValue(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        pencilButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pencil);
        eraserButton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.eraser);

        pencilButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked(pencilButton);
            }
        });

        eraserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked(eraserButton);
            }
        });

        Log.d("Toolbar Inflation", "Inflating ToolbarFragment...");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_toolbar, container, false);

    }
}
```

**EDIT: ** Here is the matching XML file as well.

fragment_toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pencil"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/pencil"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/eraser"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/eraser"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: where are `R.id.pencil` and `R.id.eraser` declared?

Comment: they are in the XML file, which I have added to the main question body.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of your part of code is that in Fragment you have to inflate the view. You are inflating it only when you return it. Try to change your `onCreateView`in this way:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_toolbar, container, false);
        pencilButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pencil);
        eraserButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.eraser);

        pencilButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked(pencilButton);
            }
        });

        eraserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked(eraserButton);
            }
        });

        Log.d("Toolbar Inflation", "Inflating ToolbarFragment...");
        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an exception because you're trying to call functionality on `ImageButtons` before they're inflated. See how your inflater inflates after your setOnCallListener?

In your `onCreateView`, you're referencing Buttons, `pencilButton` and `eraserButton` improperly by calling your `findViewById()` off of getActivity.

Instead, transplant that logic to `onViewCreated` and call your `findViewById(R.id.xxx)` on the `View` parameter.

Comment: And just as a note, getActivity().findViewById(R.id.xxx) is generally really bad practice.

Comment: I wasn't aware. What would be a better method?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_toolbar, container, false);

    pencilButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pencil);
    eraserButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.eraser);

    pencilButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked(pencilButton);
        }
    });

    eraserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicked(eraserButton);
        }
    });

    Log.d("Toolbar Inflation", "Inflating ToolbarFragment...");
    return view;

}
```